# .Net Crystal Reports - Parameters Current Values being wiped?

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I am using VS2010 and Crystal Reports Version 11R2

I have noticed a weird feature in crystal reports and was wondering if anyone has noticed. (has a work around for)

When you refresh a report it brings up the parameter prompt at first with the default values but after that it will use the last used parameters so if you just wanted to do a quick refresh of data you can.

This works as expected on reports that are not saved.

HOWEVER

on reports that have saved data the first time you refresh the values that are shown are not the currently used parameters they are in fact the defaults or blank if no default is set.

After this first initial time it works as expected until you close and open the report again.

I have also noticed this in a test application with only code to log into the report.

if anyone could provide any information on this it would be good, i am also going to attempt to log this on the SAP forum.

Comment: I am not able to get after HOWEVER, please reframe the text and explain, so that I can also test at my end.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

When you load a report that has saved data I.E. you saved the report with parameters entered, when you next load the report it loads with the saved data and therefore doesn't prompt you to enter parameters.

Because of the report is loaded with saved data the report will not be up to date so the user would want to click refresh and potentially use the same parameters.

However when you click refresh it prompts for parameters but the values already entered are either the default value or the blank if no default is set.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone that has viewed this, this has half been solved by Don off of SAP Forums.

It turns out the issue i am explaining was broken in Crystal Reports 2008 and has now been passed onto their Dev Team.

Luke

[SAP Forum Post](http://scn.sap.com/message/15722066)